# React Native - AWS Mobile Hub + AWS Cognito + Facebook Authentication

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to authenticate the users on my React Native app with Facebook but I'm struggling so much to get it done.

I already have a Mobile Hub on AWS with everything configured. I also have the Facebook SDK working perfectly as well.

I'm already able to get the user access token coming from Facebook and, once I try to persist the user with "Auth.federatedSignIn" to AWS, using the "aws-amplify" library, it returns with the status of "authenticated: false", and if I check the Federated Identity Pool, authentications are all as "Unauthenticated".

### **I'm calling the function below after I get the facebook accessToken and also the user's details from facebook graph:**

```
Auth.federatedSignIn('facebook', { token: accessToken, expires_at: expirationTime }, userData)
  .then(credentials => {
    console.log('credentials', credentials)
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

### **And it returns:[image: return]**

### **The AWS Federated Identity Pool dashboard:**

[image: img]

### **The main question is:**

What I have to do to authenticate my users using this method and also persist their data such as email, name, birthday, etc.? I also really want to use the Mobile Hub features as it will be easier to call my lambda functions, APIs, etc...

Comment: Note that you should mask the values of `sessionToken` and `secretAccessKey` here... anyone in possession of those could impersonate your user until the credentials expire.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it's a dev and test environment. There is nothing to worry about.